# R: Nested for loop using indices won't overwrite data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, nested-loops, overwrite

I have the following data frame:

```
          ID<-seq(1:5)  #patient ID
          snp1<-c("A","T","A","A","T")
          snp2<-c("C","C","0","C","C")
          snp3<-c("A","G","A","A","G")
          snp4<-c("T","0","C","G","T")
          snp5<-c("G","G","G","G","A")
          dat<-data.frame(ID,snp1,snp2,snp3,snp4,snp5)
          print(dat)
```

which gives:

```
  ID snp1 snp2 snp3 snp4 snp5
1  1    A    C    A    T    G
2  2    T    C    G    0    G
3  3    A    0    A    C    G
4  4    A    C    A    G    G
5  5    T    C    G    T    A
```

I am trying to use a nested for loop to calculate the number of occurrences of a given value for each column in dat. To start, I create an empty data frame where the columns are snps1-5 and the rows indicate the possible values each column can take in dat:

```
results<- data.frame(matrix(0,ncol = 5, nrow = 5))
colnames(results)=c("snp1","snp2","snp3","snp4","snp5")
rownames(results)=c("A","T","C","G","0")
```

To make sure the code I want to incorporate in my loop works, I do the following:

```
results["A","snp1"]<-nrow(subset(dat,subset= snp1=="A"))
print(results)
```

which correctly gives 3 for snp1 in dat having A three times:

```
  snp1 snp2 snp3 snp4 snp5
A    3    0    0    0    0
T    0    0    0    0    0
C    0    0    0    0    0
G    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
```

I then use the following nested for loop to do the same for each column (first for loop) but repeat the process for each of the possible values a column in dat can take (second for loop):

```
for(i in colnames(results)){for(j in c("A","T","C","G","0")){
            snp<-as.name(i)
            results[j,i]=nrow(subset(dat,subset= snp==j))
            results
          }}
print(results)
```

which gives a data frame completely filled with 0's:

```
  snp1 snp2 snp3 snp4 snp5
A    0    0    0    0    0
T    0    0    0    0    0
C    0    0    0    0    0
G    0    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    0    0    0
```

I've spent hours online trying to determine what the problem is but am at loss for an explanation. I was originally hoping to do this process depending on the value of a phenotype column added to dat such that I get counts for cases and controls, but I cannot get past this point. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a function that does the right thing for one column, e.g.,

```
fun = function(x)
    table(factor(x, levels = c("A", "C", "G", "T", "0")))
```

then apply it to all columns

```
apply(dat[,-1], 2, fun)
```

Probably it is much better to use `NA` rather than 0 to represent missing values; adjust the function to work in that case

```
fun = function(x)
    table(factor(x, levels = c("A", "C", "G", "T")), useNA = "always")
```

Answer (score 0):

When working in a loop like this, I prefer to subset using the indices.  That is, change `subset(dat,subset= snp==j)` to `dat[dat[, i] == j, ]`.  I hope this helps!

Of course, you don't have to use a loop for a problem like this.  You could do,

```
values <- c("A","T","C","G","0")
apply(dat[, -1], 2, function(x) sapply(values, function(y) length(which(x == y))))
```

Comment: Thank you! Both solutions worked beautifully, although I prefer the latter as it is much more elegant. I'm still not sure why my strategy using the subset() function didn't work though compared to using your indices strategy.